# How to make e in e^x written upright and why \me^x does not work?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'd like to write `e^x` in LaTeX math mode where the `e` is written upright, rather than slanted, to indicate that it is not a variable. Kopka and Daly (4ed) pg. 285 do this with `\me^x`. When I try this I get the "undefined control sequence" error.

Q: Is `\me` a deprecated command?

Q: How can I do now what `\me` used to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to define yourself that command in your document preamble

```
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
```

## **Some comments**

It's not necessary to declare this symbol as an ordinary symbol because by rule all math characters that are subject to alphabet changes are ordinary.

The construction `\mathrm{e}` is essentially equivalent to

```
\begingroup\mathgroup=0 e\endgroup
```

because the Roman math alphabet corresponds to the math group 0. Each math alphabet (`\mathrm`, `\mathnormal`, `\mathbf` and so on) corresponds to the choice of one among 16 math groups; `\mathrm` is 0, `\mathnormal` is 1, the others are from 4 onwards.

Each character has a `\mathcode` which, for `e` is `"7165` which means

> when an `e` is found in math mode, it should be an ordinary symbol, taken from the font in math group 1 at slot `"65`; but if `\mathgroup` is set to a non negative value, use the character at slot `"65` from the font in the specified math group (this because of the first digit `"7`).

Thus calling `\mathrm{e}` is like asking for a math code `"0065` (numbers preceded by `"` are hexadecimal): the first 0 means "ordinary symbol", the second one is the math group. With `\mathbf{e}` we would ask for `"0465`, according to the normal LaTeX setup.

Details about math codes are in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic. Note that LaTeX calls `\mathgroup` the primitive `\fam`.

Comment: wouldn't `\DeclareMathOperator{\me}{e}` be preferred in this case though?

Comment: @brianjd: Because this creates an atom of operator kind an the “e” should be ordinary, I think …

Comment: @brianjd No, as it would create a space in $\me x$ or $x\me$, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @brianjd: But `e` is not an operator, it's a number.

Answer (score 5):

I do this using the `unicode-math` package to redefine the alphabet used for `e` as upright.  That way, I can write `\(e^{i \pi}\)` and have everything typeset in just the right font shape.

My particular method of doing this is rather complicated (as I mix colours in as well: reals are redish and complex are a shade of purple) but the documentation for `unicode-math` is fairly straightforward.  Here's a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\setmathfont[math-style=upright,range={`e,`i}]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\(e^{i \pi} = -1\)
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: upright e]

Caveats:

1. You have to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` for this
2. The above uses the STIX fonts, if you don't have them you'll need to change the example
3. You have to be sneaky if you want to use both `e` and *`e`* in the same document (as bare symbols that is)
4. Of course, `\pi` should have been upright as well (since it is also a constant) but that's a little more complicated
5. Once you mix colours in, the whole thing can get a little silly!

Comment: It's actually sort of surprising that a mathematician would typeset `e` and `i` upright. I've only ever seen physicists do that. But that aside, you can do this without xelatex simply by writing `\mathcode"65"65` in the preamble. Similarly for `i`.

Comment: @TH. I do this in lectures to quickly distinguish between constants and variables (or local constants).  I wouldn't do this in an article.  I didn't know about the `\mathcode` trick, but I suspect it wouldn't work for the full range of what I do in lectures (such as colours).

Comment: @TH. A better way to express your trick would be ``\mathcode`e=`e`` that carries more semantics.

Comment: @LoopSpace If e and i are going to be upright, shouldn't pi be as well?

Comment: @TH., I was surprised to see that The Princeton Companion to Mathematics ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7sd01), [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:1242.00016)) sets ‘e’ and ‘i’ in upright type. It doesn't seem to do this with ‘π’, though.