# Equivalent of \mathup for upright text in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, roman

To insert text in mathmode, there are a couple of commands:

- `\mathrm` for Roman script,
- `\mathbf` for bold weight,
- `\mathit` for italic shape,
- `\mathsf` for the sans serif variant,

and so on. Now, sometimes I would like to have some math entities typeset upright (see for example [How to best typeset "special" constants (complex unit i, Euler's number e,...)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58067/how-to-best-typeset-special-constants-complex-unit-i-eulers-number-e)).
I understand that `\mathrm` sets the text in Roman *and* upright, but in some cases I do not want serifs (e.g., in presentations). The command `\mathup` does not seem to exist.

What is recommended way to set upright text in math mode?

Comment: `\mathsf`? See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Formatting_mathematics_symbols).

Comment: @Jubobs I would not want to have sanf serif script in a serif environment. I really only want to have `\upshape`.

Comment: There is a definition of `\mathup`: [Is \mathrm really preferable to \text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98008)

Comment: Doesn't \text{} from amsmath do the trick?

Comment: @Thoge Quoting from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98008: "As has been said, \text is for text, and will change depending on the surrounding font. But math symbols in a document should always look the same: The meaning of a symbols also depends on the font used. So you should not use \text for mathematical symbols.".

Comment: What about `\newcommand{\mathup}[1]{\text{\textup{#1}}}`? This works for me.

Answer (score 18):

I guess what you are seeing is the following when you use `\mathrm` with a serif font:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \( x y \mathrm{x} \text{\textup{x}}\)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

There are two ways to fix this: one fairly drastic option is to put

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}
```

but this may feed through to places you are not expecting.  An alternative is to replace the two relevant definitions from `beamerbasefont.sty` by

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{cmss}{\mddefault}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{cmss}{\bfdefault}{n}}
```

in your preamble.  In the beamer style file `{cmss}` is `{\rmdefault}`.

Applied to the above example, either method gives you:

[image: Second sample]

Answer (score 6):

The package `unicode-math` for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX does the job and offers `\mathup`.

Comment: It seems that unicode-math turns sans-serif math into serif math (try the beamer example from above). Any way around this?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer No, `beamer` is messing around.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Ah, you're right. It's all derived from the fact, that upright and italic in math (may) have different meaning, just as serif and sans serif. You should look into the documentation of `unicode-math` (if you want to use an OpenMath-font) or `mathspec` (if you want to use another font). And still, beamer messes around with that.

Comment: If one uses `unicode-math` is `\symup` acceptable for math mode text, as in text sub/superscripts?

Comment: You can load `unicode-math` with the option `mathrm=sym` and it will use the correct font.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was: in what cases to use sans serif in math.

In Czech traditional typography (and maybe in the middle Europe too) the vectors and matrices are signed by **sans serif bold** slanted (or upright) variants. This math alphabet was not preloaded by default in plain TeX (and derived formats), so we are seeing **serifs** bold in such cases in typical TeX documents, unfortunately.

The Unicode math fonts include many math alphabets including bold sans-serif upright and slanted Latin and Greek, so there is no problem. But there is strong tradition in TeX documents to use serif bold although there is no technical limitations when we are using Unicode math fonts today.

Answer (score 0):

If using pandoc with th xelatex-engine to render a PDF `\symup` was the correct solution for me to have upright units like so `\symup{{\mu}m}`, for example.

My tex-template is loading **unicode-math** instead of **mathspec** despite xelatex is being used. Fortunately I might add, because a not resolved bug in mathspec is preventing it's use together with `\siunitx`, because it requires `\amsmath` loaded before and throws this error even if I do so in the template used by pandoc.