# Shouldn't Beamer redefine \mathrm?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

`beamer` does switch to a sans serif font for math. However, it does not redefine `\mathrm`. I think it should do so. I have a few formulas that use `\mathrm` to get upright characters and they look ugly with `beamer`.

Do you agree or did I miss something?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  $abc\mathrm{abc}$
\end{document}
```

---

PS. I know how I could get properly looking formulas with `beamer`. I am not asking for help in this regard. In fact, I am suggesting an improvement (or even bugfix) here and would like to discuss how well the `beamer` package is written with regard to that issue.

Argument: Other packages that define sans-serif math fonts redefine `\mathrm` as upright math (sans-serif) font. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
  $abc\mathrm{abc}$
\end{document}
```

---

`cmbright`, `sfmath` and `arevmath` all redefine `\mathrm` as upright sans-serif font. So I'd say `beamer` is the odd one here and should be changed.

Comment: I would use `\text{abc}` and/or `\DeclareMathOperator{}{}` (both from `amsmath`) as appropriate to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: Related: [How to get `beamer` math to look like `article` math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764)

Comment: I don't see it is a bug in `beamer`. If anything, it strikes me as buggy to make `\mathrm` equivalent to `\mathsf`. (Except in the case where the entire document is to be in sans, I guess. So maybe `beamer` qualifies there. But I've never liked setting the default roman family to sans either as it just makes the effects of `\rmfamily` etc. more opaque.)

Answer (score 3):

As Paul Gessler suggested, you can use `\text{}` instead of `\mathrm{}` when you want upright rather than specifically roman text. Since you are using `beamer`, you don't even need to load any additional packages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  $abc\text{abc}$
\end{document}
```

[image: upright sans in maths mode]

If you are producing an article version as well, you obviously want TeX to do the right thing in that case, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
  $abc\text{abc}$
\end{document}
```

[image: upright roman in maths mode]

This works because by default, `beamer` loads several `ams` packages. If you are not using `beamer`, you would need to load them yourself as Paul Gessler mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps `\textup`

Comment: Sorry, `\mathrm` and `\text` are two very different concepts. They look the same in beamer but they are generally not interchangable. First, because of math operators, other math features and spaces. Second, many documents have completely different math and text fonts.

Comment: @mh543 You indicated in the question that it was just certain characters needed in upright. So I didn't think you would need it for maths operators etc. Probably in that case you need to define a `\mathup`.

Comment: It'd be nice if the down-voter would say *why*.

Answer (score 1):

You get what you ask for: Roman text.

For advice on this, see [Equivalent of \mathup for upright text in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/equivalent-of-mathup-for-upright-text-in-math-mode)

Comment: I see it differently. "Roman" denotes the standard upright font, in contrast to italic, bold or light variants. See http://www.linotype.com/en/526/Helvetica-family.html as an example, where Helvetica Roman is available.

Comment: No, you are confusing `family` with `shape`. You want to change the shape to upright (from italics), keeping the sans-serif family. This is what `\textup` and `\upshape` does for you in normal text. `\textrm` and `\rmfamily` gives you the Roman family, in latex this means glyphs with serifs.

Comment: Then please help me to understand it correctly. What does `\mathrm` refer to and does it differ in meaning from `\mathit` or `\mathbf`? I read the LaTeX companion and found no definite answer. -- I know however that `cmbright` redefines `\mathrm` with a sans-serif font. So you would say `beamer` is right and `cmbright` is buggy?

Comment: `cmbright`, `sfmath` and `arevmath` all redefine `\mathrm` as upright sans-serif font.

Comment: @mh543 Because they put a sans serif in the “roman” place in LaTeX. So `\mathrm` points to the roman font, which happens to *not* have serifs.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}
  $abc\mathrm{abc}$
\end{document}
```

Then beamer doesn't change the math fonts.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question.