# Using/Forcing upright text within theorem environment

Tags: macros, formatting, environments, theorems, text

I would like to write an equation within a theorem that involves an integrand and the upright symbol `$ \textrm{d} $` which I have abbreviated in my preamble with

```
\newcommand{\dmath}{\textrm{d}}
```

(and the preamble also contains)

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
... etc
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

I have the following theorem:

```
\begin{theorem}[Fubini's theorem]
\label{app:thrm:fubini}
Suppose $ X $ and $ Y $ are measurable spaces. If $ f(x,y) $ is integrable ($ f(x,y) $ is measurable and $ \int_{X,Y} \left| f(x,y)\right| \dmath (x,y) < \infty$) then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X} \left(\int_{Y} f(x,y) \dmath y \right) \dmath x
=
\int_{Y} \left(\int_{X} f(x,y) \dmath x \right) \dmath y
=
\int_{X,Y} f(x,y) \dmath (x,y).
\end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
```

and have the following output

[image: Output within theorem environment]

but would like the `\dmath` to produce $\textrm{d}$ to produce an upright 'd' character whenever it is called, and would like the following output:

[image: Desired result with correct formatting of upright mathematical symbols]

Any suggestions on a simple way to achieve the desired result?

I have looked at the following Qs but they don't quite address the issue:

- [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/non-italic-text-in-theorems-definitions-examples?newreg=dd281c63729c4321b5efd656f756afd4)
- Equivalent of \mathup for upright text in math mode? (*see link below)

  - `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/equivalent-of-mathup-for-upright-text-in-math-mode`

Comment: `\newcommand{\dmath}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a better reimplementation; `\mathrm` will *always* choose upright medium, whereas `\textrm` will retain the settings of the font current outside the formula.

Note some further refinements. See [Better automatic spacing of differential d?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/better-automatic-spacing-of-differential-d) for more information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\dmath}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Fubini's theorem]
\label{app:thrm:fubini}
Suppose $ X $ and $ Y $ are measurable spaces. If $ f(x,y) $ is integrable
\textup{(}$ f(x,y) $ is measurable and
$ \int_{X,Y} \lvert f(x,y)\rvert \dmath (x,y) < \infty$\textup{)} then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X} \left(\,\int_{Y} f(x,y) \dmath y \right) \dmath x
=
\int_{Y} \left(\,\int_{X} f(x,y) \dmath x \right) \dmath y
=
\int_{X,Y} f(x,y) \dmath (x,y).
\end{equation*}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use `\dmath`, though, because `breqn` uses it and you never know if you're going to reuse the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, and aslo the heads up about `breqn`. I had worried that my choice of `\dmath` might have been used previously. Thanks @egreg