# If mathcode is used to typeset e and i upright, how to force it italics again?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic

I'm using `\mathcode"69"69` in the preamble, as proposed in a comment in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/how-to-make-e-in-ex-written-upright-and-why-mex-does-not-work), to automatically typeset e and i upright in mathematical equations.

The question is, is there a way to get an italics *i* f.ex. as an index in math mode later? If so, how?

I tried `$\mathit{i}$`, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands can be defined using the old mathcode settings for `i` and `e`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\iti=\mathcode`\i
\mathchardef\ite=\mathcode`\e
\mathcode`\i=`\i
\mathcode`\e=`\e

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
4 + 7i = 4e^{10} + b_\iti^\ite
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Upright and italics for e and i]