# Formatting a fractional exponent in display math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions

Typographically, what is the correct way to display a fractional exponent in display math mode? There was a post regarding inline math, but consider this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^{3/2} x     
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The spacing becomes especially pronounced if a partial derivative follows, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^{3/2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Should one use the `\frac{}{}` function for fractional exponents at all? Or is it better to just use `x^2/4t` instead?

Comment: The output generated by the expression `\frac{1}{t}^{3/2}` is ambiguous: Does the exponent ("3/2") apply to the entire fraction, or just to the numerator? Either add some parentheses, or write `t^{-3/2}`.

Comment: @Mico I edited the code accordingly. Thanks for all your help today.

Comment: In your quest to master the writing of mathematics, I strongly recommend you go to this site ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf ` Mathematics into Type` by Swanson and study the pdf for the reference you were given by Gonzalo Medina in the preceding question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254785/e-vs-exp-in-display-mode.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Thank you for providing access to that reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's better from a *typographic* point of view -- inline-style fractions or display-style fractions while in display-math mode -- depends crucially on the contents of the fractional terms.

For the two examples at hand, I can see nothing wrong with using inline-math notation, shown on the right-hand side of the two rows below.

[image]

Incidentally, I'd say that `\left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^{3/2}` is less than perfect, typographically speaking, *not* because of the presence of the fractional term `\frac{1}{t}` but because there's *too much whitespace* between `\left( \frac{1}{t}\right)` and the exponent (`3/2`). If you must use these  large round parentheses, you should probably write

```
\left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^{\!3/2}
```

i.e., insert a negative thinspace before `3/2`, in order to "snug up" the exponent material to the closing parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
        \left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^{3/2} 
        &\text{ vs.\ } 
        t^{-3/2} \\
        \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} 
        &\text{ vs.\ }
        \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^{-1/2}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```