# Delta-equal to symbol and matrix with dashed lines

Tags: matrices

How do i write this in latex plz

[image]

Comment: welcome to TEXSE, what have to tried so-far? Because, please note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: Pls ask only one substantive question per posting.

Comment: Although I answered, you should look symbols up here first: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: As an alternative to the equal with the upper-case delta above it, you may like to use an equal with "def" above it. This is given by the macro `\eqdef` from package `mismath`.

Comment: And see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\begin{equation*}
    w \overset{\Delta}{=}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        w^1\\
        \verb!---!\\
        w^2
    \end{bmatrix}
    \overset{\Delta}{=}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        p\\
        \verb!-------------!\\
        [exp(q_n/\pi)]r^3
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

to render

[image]

`\overset` places the first argument over the second argument and `\verb` renders out exactly what its argument is in code form (kind of like the difference between code and text in Stack Exchange!).

Please note that both `overset` and the `bmatrix` environment are provided by the `amsmath` package, so make sure to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your preamble.

Comment: The next time can you put, please, the full code? And exp has a command \exp in roman into math-mode: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254785/e-vs-exp-in-display-mode.+1 for me

Answer (score 5):

In Unicode, ≜ is U+225C.   This symbol is `\triangleq` in `amssymb`, `unicode-math` and many other packages.